# Loop keeps repeating itself within Sub

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
 Public Sub progselector()
    Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\PC83-USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\generic_print_v2\generic_print_v2\programs.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Dim fcount As Integer
    Dim fldnamecombo As String
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    Dim querycommand As New SqlCommand
    command.Connection = connection
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    command.CommandText = " select field_name from field where program_name = '" & Program_nameComboBox.SelectedItem & "'; select count(field_name) from field where program_name = '" & Program_nameComboBox.SelectedItem & "' ; select field_name,field_value,sort_priority from fieldvalue where program_name ='" & Program_nameComboBox.SelectedItem & "'"
    'THIS SECTION LOADS DATA FROM THE TABLES'
    Try

        connection.Open()
        Field_nameComboBox.Items.Clear()
        dr = command.ExecuteReader


        While dr.Read()

            fldnamecombo = dr(0)

            Field_nameComboBox.Items.Add(fldnamecombo)
            Field_nameComboBox.SelectedItem = fldnamecombo
            Field_nameComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0

        End While

        dr.NextResult()
        While dr.Read
            fcount = dr(0)
            If fcount = 0 Then
                Field_nameComboBox.Text = ""
                Field_nameComboBox.SelectedItem = ""
                Field_valueComboBox.Items.Clear()
                Field_valueComboBox.Text = ""
                Field_valueComboBox.SelectedItem = "'"
                lbl_fld_fieldv.Text = "0"
                Sort_priorityLabel1.Visible = False
                lbl_field_sortprio.Visible = False
                Field_valueComboBox.Visible = False
                lbl_field_fvalues.Visible = False
            End If
            dr.NextResult()
            lbl_field_fldno.Text = fcount
        End While

       While dr.Read()
          txtbx_field_list.Text += dr(0)
       End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Heya,

I am currently having an issue with how the txtbx_field_list line is appearing. The results are supposed to be 
T1F
T2F
T3F

However, for some reason it just keeps repeating itself.So T1F T2F T3F T1F T2F T3F T1F T2F T3F.
This is called in the Selected Index Changed Sub. Do i have to place a break somewhere? Or am i calling this in the wrong way. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use nextresult and why are you looping thru these over and over again?  You are only grabbing one piece of information from the tables, so why not add that information into an arraylist, array, generic list or hash table (whatever you prefer) and then cycle thru that for the rest?

In general, try to keep the sql connection open for as little as possible.  A loop this small wouldn't impact anything, but when you start getting into more complicated pulls and object referencing, it can take awhile.

```
dim temparr as new arraylist()
While dr.Read()
    temparr.add(dr.item("field_name"))
End While

If temparr.count = 0 Then
   Field_nameComboBox.Text = ""
   Field_valueComboBox.Items.Clear()
   lbl_fld_fieldv.Text = "0"
   Sort_priorityLabel1.Visible = False
   lbl_field_sortprio.Visible = False
   Field_valueComboBox.Visible = False
   lbl_field_fvalues.Visible = False
else
   lbl_field_fldno.Text = temparr.count
   for each l_item as string in temparr
    txtbx_field_list.Text += l_item
    Field_nameComboBox.Items.Add(l_item)
   next  
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me simplify the code! I was taught to use dr.read alot previously. However txtbx_field_list.text += l_item still puts too many results out. It works if I call the sub at the load but once i put it in the selected index changer it repeats the results multiple times.

Comment: Ah I managed to solve it! Turns out I had to put a txtbx_field_list.clear if it were empty. Thanks !